# Adding reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

A question here, I recently installed a software on my computer which comes with a new DLL.
I used it as a reference to my source-controlled project. Now, when I am trying to work on my application using a different computer. It's not finding the DLL for the device. Is there something I can do to fix this / include the DLL so it wont throw an error? or do I also have to install the software on each of the computer?

Thanks

Comment: Does the software allow you to distribute the DLL or does it want you to install their software package on each computer it is being used on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest route would be to create a folder within your project to store dependency DLLs, and just copy them in from wherever they normally live.  You can then add this local folder to the source control for your project.  Within your project itself, when you create the reference to the DLL, you'll want to reference the local copy rather than the copy that was installed from the product.  Note that if this DLL has other dependencies, you'll probably need local copies of those as well.

Like Joel Kennedy said in a comment, you may want to double-check that the provider of the DLL is okay with redistribution of the DLL.

Also note that the local copy method works for most .NET assemblies, but it may not work for COM or certain types of .NET assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have the DLL on each computer with which you wish to develop.  You could try including the DLL in the source control...  I've never done that though so I can't offer any tips.

Comment: I've added "source" dlls to source control before.  It's a pretty handy way to make sure the entire team is working with the same / correct version.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install the dll on each computer along with the items it depends on.

If this is a COM dll, you'll have to register it (obviously).